# Difficulty in escaping single quote character while SQLite database insertion

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, titanium

I have to insert certain text in database which may contain characters with single quotes and double quotes.

For eg: **"Lumix"** or something like **Vijay's**

I have successfully escaped the double quotes like this:

```
if(fdata.search('"') != -1) {


fdata = fdata.replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1");



}
```

But I am not understanding how to escape the single quotes. Without escaping the single quotes SQLite is not accepting the data. How to solve the issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't your database API give you bound variables or an SQLite-specific escaping function?

Comment: It is written in javascript, titanium appcelerator, not java native

Comment: @kittu88: So? Titanium Appcelerator includes a database API, which _does_ support bound variables (aka parameters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameters, then you don't need to escape anything:

```
db.execute('INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, Name) VALUES(?, ?)', 123, name);
```

Comment: what about the update query? db.execute("UPDATE formData SET  form_xml_id=" + findex + ",dateTime_stamp='" + datetime + "',data='" + "" + "',user_id=" + Ti.App.information.user_id + ",status='"+ DataStatus +"' where unique_id='" + Ti.App.mydata._guid + "'");

Comment: Same principle: `db.execute("UPDATE formData SET form_xml_id=?, dateTime_stamp=?, data=?, user_id=?, status=?, where unique_id=?", findex, datetime, '', Ti.App.information.user_id, DataStatus, Ti.App.mydata._guid);` :-)

Comment: See the documentation here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database.DB-method-execute

Answer (score 1):

CL.'s answer is the by far best solution, but if you want to make this work without rewriting your code you could add this function:

```
function removeQuotes(str){
return str.replace(/'/g, "&#39;").replace(/"/g,"&quot;");
}
```

Usage:

```
fdata = removeQuotes(fdata);
```

That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceAll` method for replacing `'(single quote)` with `space` as below:

```
     String name= name.replaceAll("'", "''");
```

Comment: try fdata.replace(/["']/g, "")

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı: that would only remove all the (single and double) quote characters, not espace them...

Comment: sqlquery.replace(/'/g, "''");